# How to execute specific test classes from testng.xml file through eclipse or command line

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <suite name="AutomationTestSuite" allow-return-values="true"  verbose="10" >
    <test name="Login">
      <classes>
         <class name="com.proj.tests.Login" />
      </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="OpenandEdit">
      <classes>
         <class name="com.proj.tests.OpenandEdit" />
      </classes>
    </test> 
     <test name="CasesGroup">
       <groups>
         <run>
           <class name="CasesMenu"/>
           <class name="CasesExport"/>
         </run>
       </groups>  
     </test>
```

Given above is the testng.xml file which has all classes listed. How do i run only test classes in groups tag. or is there any other way we can execute selected set of test classes from testng.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out **Login** and **OpenandEdit** Test Classes and Run as TestNG

Comment: Sequential Execution or Parallel Execution? Does **CasesGroup** depends on **Login** and **OpenandEdit** classes?

Comment: Running Whole xml file works ? do you want to run it Sequential or Parallel ?

Answer (score 0):

> How do i run only test classes in groups tag

By specifying the group you want to run.

```
...
<test name="Regression1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <exclude name="brokenTests"  />
      <include name="checkinTests"  />
    </run>
  </groups>
</test>
...
```

To run, just <kbd>Right Click</kbd>+<kbd>Run as TestNG Suite</kbd>