# How to run test from testng.xml on Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

I have testng.xml suite file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="NewSuite">
    <test name="RegressionTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="path.to.testclass.MainTests" />
            <class name="path.to.testclass.MainTests2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="SmokeTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="path.to.testclass.MainTests2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How to run only test classes from RegressionTest. I tried `mvn clean test -Dtest=RegressionTest` but it doesn't works. If I run `mvn clean test` on Jenkins it runs all test classes in textng.xml

My surefire plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Thx for help.

Comment: I think you should add `<groups>`, as an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/19961616/2504101